# how to use python and c++ at the same time in vscode

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code

I change my IDE from MSVS to VS Code because I want to use python with c++ for codeforce.
However, there is a problem that I can't run my python file even though I add python configuration in 'launch.json'.

Below picture is my workspace folder.

[image]

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
      "name": "g++.exe - 활성 파일 빌드 및 디버그",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "디스어셈블리 버전을 Intel(으)로 설정",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe 활성 파일 빌드"
    }
  ]



 {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 활성 파일 빌드",
      "command": "D:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "디버거에서 생성된 작업입니다."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Error log says, "active file is not c or c++ file, so cannot build it"

How can I run python files in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, there a little run button at the top right of the python file you are opening pressing it should run your program

[image: This button]

It not the best solution, other can think of better way but use this for now until other help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't run correctly. In the project, VS Code can't find python interpreter though there is a global python which version is 3.8. System find python.exe from C drive and run it after click that button, however my global python exists in D drive. Below is the error log.



PS C:\Users\Tofu\source\C++\Algorithm> & C:/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Tofu/source/C++/Algorithm/python/helpme.py

'C:/Python39/python.exe' this term is not cmdlet, function, script file or executable program'